# How to write a script for photoshop to type a shortcut then quick export to png also open the exported folder instantly?

Tags: windows, export, adobe, photoshop

Can it even be done?

photoshop script

here's their guide

https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Comment: Quick Expirt can't be scripted, normal export (save as/save for web) — can. 'Open the folder after' also can be done.

Comment: how to write the script that save as png also open the exported folder instantly?

Comment: What do you ask exactly? You write it as any other script. If you don't know how you learn it or you pay someone to write it for you

Comment: How do I use python to call this script? https://ibb.co/5hMZ7Lw (pg. 32) And whats app? And How to call it through shortkey F1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it can be done.

Secondly, I agree with Sergey Kritskiy in that if you don't know how to do something, learn how to do it. If you don't want to learn then pay someone a reasonable amount to do it for you.

Don't want to do that? Then at least put in the time and effort to [ask a question nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). - Not all in the the title :)

Okay, you're gonna need three things:

A **batch file** and a **Photoshop Script** and a **Photoshop Action**.

Let's assume that your folder in question is `c:\temp`

**BATCH FILE**
CD /d C:\temp
START .

Save in C:\temp as mybatch.bat

**PHOTOSHOP SCRIPT**

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF 

// variable to where you want to save the png
var myPNG = "C:\\temp\\my_png.png";


// save out the png
save_as_png(myPNG);


// call the rename batch files
var myBat = new File("C:\\temp\\mybatch.bat");


// and we now execute the bat file
File(myBat).execute();

// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL


function save_as_png(filePath)
{
  // png file options
  var pngFile = new File(filePath);
  pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  pngSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  pngSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
  pngSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE; pngSaveOptions.quality = 1;

  activeDocument.saveAs(pngFile, pngSaveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```

Save that as instant_png.jsx in a sensible place (like your Photoshop scripts folder)

In Photoshop, open a flattened image that you want to turn into a png.
Record an action (Actions palette, new action) to run a script:
When the record button is red, just head over to the file menu File > Scripts > Browse and then find and pick the Photoshop script, instant_png.jsx.
HIT THE STOP RECORDING ACTION BUTTON! - Otherwise you just continue to record everything you do in Photoshop. And we don't want that.

Now you have an action that runs a Photoshop script that calls a batch file. :)

Assign a hotkey in Photoshop to that action. And bingo! you're done.

Comment: save CD /d C:\temp START . as .bat?

Comment: Which section in photoshop scripting guide mention opens the exported folder ?
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-scripting-guide-2020.pdf

Comment: The batch file is two lines `CD /d C:\temp` goes to the C drive and changes the directory to C:\temp - assuming that's where you want the folder to open. `CD Start .` will open said directory as Windows Explorer

Comment: Page 31 talks about file saving files, but calling a batch file won't be something you find in a manual. That comes with experience and knowledge.

Comment: That's probably because you don't have a temp folder on C: Change `CD /d C:\temp` to whatever is the folder you want to open `CD /d C:\myprojects\export` or `CD /d C:\something\something else\some folder` If there are spaces in the path you will need quotes around it. `CD /d "C:\something\something else\some folder"`

Comment: https://ibb.co/g9bpFpX still not working, only export works but no pop up folder

Comment: [have a look at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)